Is there any rule about how far wiring has to be from a ceiling's surface?
In my house, the basement is unfinished, and many of the cables and pipes are attached near the bottom edge of joists and beans. If I want to put up a ceiling, does code require that I somehow relocate these upward (or to the ceiling surface) or install anti-nailing plates, as would be the case for walls, or would that only be true if and where these go through the wood members?
Given that it's existing wiring and piping, would grandfatherimg affect that at all?
Or should I be looking at dropped ceilings, even though the ceiling height is already only 7 ft at the deep end at less than six feet at the shallow end. (Extension versus original foundation.)
Or just give up and leave it open?
(Single question: if and how I can install a ceiling given this existing wiring. I'll rewrite when I get a chance)

A pic or 2 of the ceiling and wiring you are dealing with would help, please.

Seeing most of us will miss the edge of wood with screws/nails the odd time, it would probably be a good idea to use the same distance as with wire/pipe in studs.  Seeing most joists/beams are straight, careful marking of the edge/s will help, if moving is difficult.

Some places do not like low ceilings, so might want to check the local regulations.

Ideally you will bore holes in the joists and relocate the cables up to run through the holes.
If you can't relocate the cables for whatever reason, you'll have to space your ceiling below the joists.  You can protect them with raceway or conduit, then fasten furring strips the bottom of the joists to space the drywall (or whatever material) ceiling below the conduit.  Nailer plates over the gaps where you have cable wouldn't be a bad idea.

That makes perfect sense to me. And inclines me toward just removing the mostly superfluous insulation, painting, vacuuming occasionally, and calling it good enough.  Claim it's "industrial chic."

Yeah, the juice may not be worth the squeeze for some aesthetics.
